# why count++ doesn't increase in my situation

Tags: javascript

```
var count=0;

function showIt(){
    if(count==0){
        alert(count);
        count++;        
    }
    alert(count);

}
```

this function is an event of onclick, the first time I click the button, I got an alert 0 and 1, but when I continue clicked the statement which is "1" did not change.  I have no idea why it does not change, I tried count=count+1, count +=1, none of them works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're only incrementing when count == 0

```
if(count==0){
    alert(count);
    count++;        
}
```

You mean

```js
var count=0;

function showIt(){
    if(count==0){
        alert(count);
    }
    count++;        
    alert(count);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showIt()">showIt</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

`count++;` is increasing your `count` variable.

The problem lies in your if statement which is `if(count==0)` , the first time `count` is zero, but afterwards `count` will be 1, hence not going into the body of the if statement and not incrementing `count` anymore.

Increment `count` outside of the if statement (don't move it to the `else` clause!).